# mysql upload size doesn't change upon changing php ini file in yosemite

Tags: php, mysql, macos

After updating to Yosemite there were a lot of changes including php and mysql versions.

I copied **php.ini.default** to **php.ini**.

Although I changed `max_upload_size value` (to 50M) in `/etc/php.ini` file, the max upload size in phpMyAdmin has not been changed.
Yes, I did not forget to restart apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`phpinfo()` from `/Library/WebServer/Documents` shows `php.ini` path as `/usr/local/php5/lib`.

Hence editing `php.ini` with `max_upload_size` to increased value did the job.

Thanks!!